# Retrofit y corrutinas con la PokeApi no me funcionan

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, android-corrutinas

intento hacer un recycler view con el nombre y la foto de los pokemon, pero no me funciona, no entiendo por qué la verdad, las peticiones no se llegan a hacer porque la lista de pokemons nunca se llena. Hago un bucle for de llamadas ya que lo que quiero es el nombre y la foto del pokemon, ya que cuando pido una lista de pokemons los objetos solo traen el nombre y la url del objeto completo y es la mejor forma que se me ha ocurrido, agradecería si me pueden echar una mano, muchas gracias.

**Este es el código de mi mainActivity:**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initRecycler()
        obtenerPokemons()

    }


    private fun initRecycler(){
        pokemonAdapter = PokemonAdapter(pokemons)
        linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerpokemon.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            adapter = pokemonAdapter
        }

    }


    private fun obtenerPokemons() {
        for (i in 1..30)  {
            searchByName(i)
        }

        pokemonAdapter.setPokemons(pokemons)
    }


    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    private fun searchByName(query:Int){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call = getRetrofit().create(PokemonService::class.java).getPokemon("pokemon/$query")
            val pokemonsResp = call.body()
            runOnUiThread {
                if(call.isSuccessful) {
                    pokemons.add(pokemonsResp)
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "No encuentro eso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Este es el código del objeto pokemon:**

```
  data class Pokemon (
        @SerializedName("id"                       ) var id                     : Int,
        @SerializedName("name"                     ) var name                   : String,
        @SerializedName("sprites"                  ) var sprites                : Sprites,
    )
    data class Sprites (
        @SerializedName("back_default"       ) var backDefault      : String,
        @SerializedName("front_default"      ) var frontDefault     : String,
    )
```

**Y este es el código de mi servicio:**

```
interface PokemonService {
    @GET
    suspend fun getPokemon(@Url url:String) : Response<Pokemon?>
}
```

Comment: Se muestra algo en el LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Log de nombre de pokemons]

Este es el log que imprimi luego de obtener el pokemon, al parecer si te trae la lista quizas el error esta al momento de mostrar los datos en tu adapter, si pudieras mostarlo podriamos descartar esa opcion, igual quisiera ver como declaraste tu lista pokemons.